Need help on finding a solution to my Work Flow project
When I run a condition statement on my workflow for when an item or a file is modified, I am trying to only throw an exception to send an email when an item is marked completed in the status category. However, it sends an email regardless of if I mark it complete or if I mark other categories like the priority of the task. I need more reputation to send photos, but the structure is this
When a item or file is created
Condition:
And
Status Value is equal to Completed
Applicable QP value is not equal to null
If yes                                                    If No
Get file properties only
Site adress: cannot address for work reasons               Send an Email(V2)
Library Name: Procedures
Limited Entries to Folder: Empty
Included Nested Items: Empty
Filter Query: Document_ID eq'Applicable_QP
Ordered By: Empty
Top Count: Empty
Limit Columns by View: Empty
Apply to Each Value
output: value
Send an Email(V2)
I tried applying a condition before the first condition that status: Priority must not equal null. I was expecting maybe for the result to not check for the Status: Priority.
Condition Statement
Steps following condition statement
Edit has been made to add picture links

Screenshots of the designer and run time variables help, too hard at the minute.
